# Non-Blocking RabbitMQ Consumer - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous

I am looking for an up to date rabbitMQ consumer written in python3.7 that can process messages in parallel.

I have found:

https://github.com/mosquito/aio-pika and
https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.12.0/examples/asyncio_consumer.html

AIO-PIKA is only working correctly when there exists a `asyncio.sleep(1)`, but I don't understand why and the asyncio_consumer example is not working asynchronously if I use an example like below (minus the async stuff).

```
async def find_divisibles(inrange, div_by):
    print("finding nums in range {} divisible by {}".format(inrange, div_by))
    located = []
    for i in range(inrange):
        if i % div_by == 0:
            located.append(i)
        if i % 50000 == 0:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.0001)

    print("Done w/ nums in range {} divisible by {}".format(inrange, div_by))
    return located
```

(From: https://pythonprogramming.net/asyncio-basics-intermediate-python-tutorial/)